# Implementing Word Selection and Interaction in React Native for Large Text Inputs

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, text

I am working on a React Native project where I have a text input that spans over a few hundred pages. My goal is to allow users to interact with individual words by double-tapping on them. When a word is selected, I want to highlight both the selected word and the entire line of text it belongs to.

I have been exploring different approaches, but I'm unsure about the best way to achieve this functionality efficiently. How can I implement word selection and interaction in React Native for such a large text input? Are there any libraries or techniques that can help me accomplish this task? I would appreciate any insights or code examples that can guide me in the right direction. Thank you!

What I Tried:
I attempted to use a FlatList in my React Native project to handle the large text input and provide a smooth user experience. By breaking down the text into individual words within  components, I hoped to implement word selection and interaction by utilizing the onPress event for double-tapping. However, I encountered some challenges with this approach.

Expectations:

Maintain Formatting: I expected the text to retain its formatting even when splitting it into individual  components within the FlatList. However, this didn't work as expected, and the formatting was lost.
Avoid Rendering Issues: Since the text input spans a few hundred pages, I wanted to avoid rendering issues. Unfortunately, using many  components in the FlatList caused rendering problems when handling such a large amount of data.
Given these issues, I am seeking guidance on the best approach to implement word selection and interaction efficiently in React Native for a large text input. My goal is to maintain text formatting and ensure smooth rendering while allowing users to double-tap on words for selection. If there are alternative techniques or libraries that can help achieve this functionality, I would greatly appreciate any suggestions or code examples. Thank you!